# Trying to leave SE Music, if I can

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts

I scheduled my SE Music account for deletion a couple of days ago. At first there was a banner at the top of my profile page that said *"This account is scheduled to be deleted 24 hours from now."* But my account has not yet been deleted, and the banner now reads: *"This account is scheduled to be deleted 21 hours ago."*

I can understand a 24 hour review period for accounts like mine that are associated with significant numbers of posts and votes, but 21 hours (and counting) beyond the stated review period seems excessive. Is this sort of lag typical when accounts are removed by users?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm really sorry to see you go; I've certainly learned a lot from you, and I always looked forward to seeing what you'd contributed. There are a lot of great reasons to leave SE (or lessen your time on it), and I wish you all the best moving forward!

Comment: PS: ex nihilo ad nihilum? :-)

Comment: @Richard -- thank you; that's very kind. I think that I've lost faith in the efficacy of this crowd-sourced Q&A model for learning and teaching about music, but there are a number of contributors here who do provide some great information. I've certainly learned lots from reading _your_ answers; I'm sure that I'll poke my head back in now and then to see what's happening. _Ex nihilo ad absurdum._

Comment: I think we'll all miss you @exnihilo :-(

Comment: Thanks @DoktorMayhem -- I meant what I said about the moderators; you guys have been incredible. It must be like herding cats ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users over a certain reputation need to manually be deleted by SE staff. [According to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/236364), most accounts deleted happen within three business days and the answer provides additional follow up steps if it's not deleted within that 3 day window.

Comment: I've deleted other SE accounts which were removed right after the 24h window, but never any that have had as much activity as this one; I didn't expect the delay. Thanks for the link, it was very helpful. In parting, you and the other mods have always done a great job here and I really appreciate all of your hard work. Don't forget to practice ;)